Syntax error using 'FOR SYSTEM_TIME AS OF ... AT TIME ZONE' in SQL Server Temporal table query
As example given here:
DECLARE @LocalTime DATETIMEOFFSET = '2021-09-01 10:00:00.7230011 -07:00';

SELECT *
FROM [vw_GetOrgChart]
FOR SYSTEM_TIME AS OF @LocalTime AT TIME ZONE 'UTC';

I get an error:

Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near 'AT'

I failed to find syntax detailed explanation for 'AT TIME ZONE' statement, except for this, any idea?

SQL Server version:  Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM-CU23) (KB5030333) - 15.0.4335.1 (X64)


Why not fix the variable value with the at time zone? For system time probably doesn't support expressions, only constants

@siggemannen linked docs suggest it's possible

Does your view definitely contain temporal tables?

@DaleK Yes. Using variable will get rid of the error, but MS docs says it can be used this way, so I wonder if I missed something.

From what I read of the docs you should be able to do that. Hopefully someone who has done it will comment. Or maybe the docs are wrong.

Or maybe the docs are wrong. Only in as much as the examples are spread out over multiple pages and there's no trace of how to create the dbo.LocationDepartments table.

I don't see anything wrong in the docs. it suggests it's possible when you fix the variable itself to be of specific timezone, see FOR SYSTEM_TIME AS OF @ASOF;

You can see it https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-transact-sql only allowed is date literal ie. '20240101' or date variables

Looks like the docs are just wrong in their example. Even against a temporal table, it doesn't work. db<>fiddle. Fortunately the docs are open source, so I (if no one else does) might make a pull request to fix it.

@ThomA but where in the docs does it says that FOR SYSTEM_TIME supports expressions. It's like, you can do: @a + 1 but you can't do: exec spX @a + 1

In the example, @siggemannen . Screenshot

@ThomA oh yeah, now i see it, yeah, looks like the docs are wrong

I've submitted a PR to remove the "offending" example.

The documentation is (was) wrong. The incorrect information, about that AT TIME ZONE could be used, was added last year, however, due diligence wasn't performed on the PR, meaning incorrect information was added (as much as I think that the docs being open source is good, it does have it's flaws too).
Randolph West confirms this on a PR I raised:

I originally authorized the PR last year that added this change, and didn't do due diligence to test it properly beforehand.
On the WideWorldImporters database, you can do this:
DECLARE @CustomerTimeZone NVARCHAR(128) = 'Central European Standard Time';

SELECT StockItemID, ValidFrom,
    --Assign the known offset only
    ValidFrom AT TIME ZONE 'Pacific Standard Time' AS OrderDate_TimeZonePST,
    --Assign the known offset, then convert to another time zone
    ValidFrom AT TIME ZONE @CustomerTimeZone AS OrderDate_TimeZoneCustomer
FROM Warehouse.StockItems;

However, you are correct, and AT TIME ZONE is not compatible with AS OF.
Instead of approving your PR directly, which removes the example entirely, I'm going to roll back the change from last year.

